# Last element of multivalued field in solr

Tags: solr, multivalue

Is there any way to get last element of multivalued field in solr. I want to run a query with search string present as the last element of multivalued field.Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to *search* only on the last element of the multivalued field?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to use UpdateRequestProcessor chain to copy only the last value into the dedicated field and search against that. You can use [LastFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/#LastFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory) for that.